# How to update table after insert through trigger?

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to update table 'sheet' after insert, below trigger is not working. Its giving syntax error;

```
CREATE TRIGGER sheet_insert AFTER INSERT ON `sheet`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE `sheet` SET `solution`="No", `status`="In Progress", `cause`="Under Investigation"
WHERE `status`=""
END;
```

Any help or guidance will be much appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
delimiter |
CREATE 
TRIGGER sheet_insert AFTER INSERT ON `sheet`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
UPDATE `sheet` SET `solution`="No", `status`="In Progress", `cause`="Under Investigation"
WHERE `status`="";
END;
delimiter ;
```